# How phpMyAdmin on Debian 10 on amazon can be linked to the domain name

Tags: phpmyadmin

The phpMyAdmin is in the directory /var/www/html/phpMyAdmin and website is in the directory /var/www/html/myweb. How can I link phpMyAdmin to the website, for example:

The website is:

```
 myweb.com
```

and I want to link phpMyAdmin with the domain name:

```
myweb.com/phpMyAdmin
```

It is fine with localhost like:

```
http://82.38.49.234/phpMyAdmin/index.php
```

As SSL certificate is not issued for IP addresses, so it does not work with https. Therefore, I want to use phpMyAdmin with the domain name, because it has a SSL certificate and works with https.

I also moved phpAdmin directory under /var/www/html/myweb/phpMyAdmin, then phpMyAdmin doesn't work. I also changed:

```
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'myweb.com';
```

but is not working. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

After trying for several days I finally explored the answer.

Go to the site hosting directory

```
 $ cd /var/www/html/myweb
```

Link symbolically with -s the hosting directory to phpMyAdmin directory. In Unix instead of giving the whole present working directory path, a period (.) can copy the file or directory. For more details about the period please see:

https://www.google.com/search?q=what+is+a+period+(.)+in+unix+command&oq=what+is+a+period+(.)+in+unix+command&aqs=chrome..69i57j33i160l2j33i22i29i30l3j33i15i22i29i30l4.20564j0j15&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

```
$ ln -s /var/www/html/phpMyAdmin .
```

Because myweb.com is under https, so on the browser just write phpMyadmin after domain name.

```
 https://myweb.com/phpMyAdmin
```

Then setup your database in phpMyAdmin.